# Which citation package is the best for obtaining the results I have below?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, apacite

[image: References Section]

[image: In text Citation]

Currently, I'm using apacite, but it's not coming out quite how I like it.  There are ampersands (&) in the references section and we'd like "et al." to appear after 3 author references.

Let me know if you have any thoughts.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE

Comment: You ask which citation [management] package is "best", how ever that may be measured, but then you also appear to require the use of the `apacite` citation management package. Please clarify our objectives and any constraints that must be satisfied.

Comment: Hi Mico.  I thought that package was the closest to what I needed. It does not need to be the apacite package.  The objective is to make it look as similar to the above citation style.

Answer (score 2):

You ask two questions. One is about how to create a citation call-out of the form

```
(Lusardi, Schneider, and Tufano 2011)
```

which features (a) an authoryear-style citation call-out format, (b) parentheses around the entire citation call-out, (c) no punctuation mark between the author list and the year, (d) an "Oxford" comma ahead of the final "and", and (e) a complete list of all authors rather than just "Lusardi et al.".

That's actually easy to handle -- except for the Oxford comma requirement. First, be sure to load the `natbib` citation management package with the options `authoryear`, `round`, and `longnamesfirst`. Second, employ a bibliography style that's compatible with the `natbib` package. Third, assuming that the entry's key is given by `lst:2011, say, write the citation command as

```
(\citealt{lst:2011})
```

The presence or absence of the Oxford comma is not determined by `natbib` but, rather, the bibliography style that's in use.

---

The second question asks which *bibliography style* might create formatted bibliographic entries that match the style of the entry shown in the screenshot. That's a much harder question. In the short run, you may want to check out the `aer` bibliography style, which meets at least five of your stylistic requirements (authors in bold; use of Oxford comma in author list in formatted entry; title in double-quote marks, journal name in italics, issue number in parentheses), but not all of them. E.g., the `aer` style does *not* employ an Oxford comma in the citation call-out.

In the medium term, you may want to familiarize yourself with the `makebst` utility of the `custom-bib` package. This utility will let you create a bespoke bibliography style that meets *all* of your formatting requirements, including some of less common ones -- such as that citation call-outs be truncated only if there are more than 3 authors. (The more common requirement is that author lists are truncated if there more than 2 authors.) I suggest you search this site for instances of the use of `makebst` for more information about this utility.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@techreport{lst:2011,
 title       = "Financially Fragile Households: Evidence and Implications",
 author      = "Lusardi, Annamaria and Schneider, Daniel J. and Tufano, Peter",
 institution = "National Bureau of Economic Research",
 address     = "Cambridge MA",
 type        = "Working Paper",
 number      = 17072,
 year        = 2011,
 URL         = "http://www.nber.org/papers/w17072",
}
@article{abc:3001,
  author = "Anne Author and Brenda Buthor and Carla Cuthor",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  journal= "Circularity Today",
  year   = 3001,
  volume = 17,
  number = 2,
  pages  = "46-100",
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[authoryear,round,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{aer}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional

\begin{document}
(\citealt{lst:2011}), (\citealt{abc:3001})
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```